# Passing model data onto another view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-identity, renderaction

So I've tried to follow multiple threads on here to do what I am to, and so far it all seems to have something to do with a singleton which I think is a bit over-the-top solution for my issue.

I'm trying to do the following:
I have my login async task which is executed when the user logins in a partial view, then it takes a LoginViewModel as a parameter, when succesfully logged in this happens:

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

Afterwards when my users click into the Member section as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Medlemsområde", "LoggedIn", "Home", null, new { @class = "login-field btn btn-primary" })
```

My home controller looks like this

```
public ActionResult LoggedIn()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return View("Dashboard");
    else
        return View("Login");
}
```

My dashboard looks like this

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("Index", "Manage");
 }
```

And then I have my Manage controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
{
            ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Dit password er blevet ændret."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Dit password er gemt."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetTwoFactorSuccess ? "Din to-faktor godkendelse er gemt."
                : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "Der skete en fejl."
                : message == ManageMessageId.AddPhoneSuccess ? "Dit telefon nummer blev tilføjet."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemovePhoneSuccess ? "Dit telefon nummer blev fjernet."
                : "";

            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var model = new IndexViewModel
            {
                HasPassword = HasPassword(),
                PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId),
                TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId),
                Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
                BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId)
            };
            return View(model);
}
```

Whenever I have

```
Html.RenderAction("Index", "Manage");
```

I get the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'ClientSideProgramming.Models.IndexViewModel', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'ClientSideProgramming.Models.LoginViewModel'.

How can I fix this without ending up with either passing models all around, or having a singleton?

Comment: Look at the error message! There is clear instruction what have to do!

Comment: @TanvirArjel but how can I solve it? I know what the error is, and I've tried a thousand things to fix it. But I'm unsure how to pass the correct model to it?

Comment: Hope I shall help you tomorrow..Its midnight in my Country.

Comment: The model defined on the Index.cshtml page should be of type IndexViewModel.

Comment: @Sandhya I already got the following at the top of my Index.cshtml, "@model ClientSideProgramming.Models.IndexViewModel"

Comment: I got it working by putting an if statement before my partial login view in the layout, so whenever dashboard is loaded and logged in,it'll function correctly. "@{ if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { Html.RenderPartial("Login"); }"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably do

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

instead of `return View("Dashboard")` when you are successfully logged in.

Comment: The entire point is that I'm trying to include the Index as a partial view inside my dashboard so I'm able to use a JavaScript to have the index aswell as other pages display at once